# Metal texture read() vs sample() performance

Tags: ios, gpu, metal

In trying to optimize my Metal rendering performance in the fragment shader, I've noticed that there are several ways to read from a texture, depending on the scenario. I was wondering if the texture read approach has performance implications.

Here are three different alternatives I've tried:

1. Using `tex2D.read()` without a sampler (uses `uint2` coordinates).
2. Using `tex2D.sample()` with pixel coordinates (uses `float2` coordinates)
3. Using `tex2D.sample()` with normalized coordinates (uses `float2` coordinates).

Should I expect performance differences in iOS between these options?

Comment: Generally sampling takes a lot of work (filtering, mipmapping, etc) but it has special hardware for it. I would expect reads to be much faster, but is only for special use cases (not just displaying a texture on a surface).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are generally similar. One might require more work than another to convert between uint2 / float2 for the coordinate, but this effect should be minor.

Read has undefined behavior for reading outside the image, so that is something to consider.

Comment: Readind outside image bounds doesn't have undefined behavior. See section 6.12 "Texture Functions" of the Metal Shading Language Specification pdf.